# Vega-lite kibana autosize with concat not working

Tags: kibana, vega-lite

I am trying to concatenate views using hconcat with vega-lite (4.17) in kibana (7.12). So far so good, however when I set autosize to none (as requested in kibana vega-lite) my plots disappear. If I set the autosize to pad (or even fit), the plots can be seen but with two horizontal bars showing two errors: Width "container" only works for single views and layered views, and the same error for height. I am not sharing any code here because it does work in vega editor, but not in kibana. At this point, I am just hoping for a workaround, so any ideas will be more than welcome! Thanks!

([Just for reference here is a ss of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMyBv.png))

Comment: Not sure what you tried in editor, but as per to documentation of autofit there are [limitations](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/size.html#limitations) which says: 'Fit does not work with other kinds of composed views (facet/hconcat/vconcat/repeat).' Also for with container other view will not work as the documentation for `container` says the same: 'This responsive mode is available only for single view or layer specifications.'

Comment: @wahab memon thanks for your fast reply! I did read the documentation, but I still think that the autosize set to type = none should not make the plot disappear right? I should be able to set width and height and actually see the plots, I believe :), and this is exactly what I don't understand! So I get it that we can't use autosize fit (or pad) with concat, so we are left with autosize type none, and no plot, so what's the point of concat if I can't see nothing? :)

Comment: with normal concat example I tried giving autosize `none` and it just shrank my width of charts. after removing autosize it worked as you mentioned. May I know the reason of providing `autosize` ?

Comment: The reason why I need to set autosize to none is that, if I don't, those warnings for width and height do not disappear (as shown in the screen shot above), and they are carried with the visualizations to the dashboard. Not an option. And the reason I am using concat is because I am trying to use a bar plot as a filter for another plot which has to be done in vega because I need to use conditional color formatting. So I am a bit stuck here